# What is this strange thing under Tu-95 which looks like a horse-fly's eye?

Tags: feature-identification, bomber

I was seeing [this photo](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8139847) and saw an strange thing under the bomber. Too much looks like a [compound eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_eye). What could be it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Obviously it's the bottom half of a disco ball.

Comment: If there was one thing the Soviets were known for, it was their disco ragers.  So many rollerskates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.ausairpower.net/APA-Bear.html) it is a **MAK-UL IR Threat Warning System**, an infrared based [missile approach warning system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missile_approach_warning_system). Here is a closer picture:

[image: IR Threat warning system]
<sup>(picture by [Miroslav Gyűrösi](http://www.ausairpower.net/APA-Bear.html))</sup>

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's so oddly coloured?

Comment: @Sanchises Nope, I tried to find more information on how it works exactly, but (at least with my Google skills) I could only find the name of this thing. I guess one needs to search for the right terms in Russian to find out more, but I don't speak Russian :(

Comment: No worries, my Russian isn't exactly up to scratch either. It just looks so puzzlingly random and strangely futuristic, I wonder what the design behind it is.

Comment: Infrared windows are often red or orange, depending on the region of the infrared spectrum where they will be used.  I would conjecture there are several types of detector for different parts of the spectrum behind the windows, and that there are several copies of each type to view different directions.  Possibly some of the "windows" are just light weight fillers.  https://www.thorlabs.com/navigation.cfm?guide_id=2367

Comment: [More information](https://basicsaboutaerodynamicsandavionics.wordpress.com/2017/02/22/electro-optical-systems/) on IR detection and sensor protection. Each material (color) filters its own band and none can do all without being subject to aerodynamic heating.